# Match the exact digit using regular expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I am querying a database table in mysql where data are store in below format.

Example:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| adv_images | start_date | end_date   |  
+------------+------------+------------+
| 21.jpg     | 2013-05-22 | 2013-05-28 |         
| 2.jpg      | 2013-05-22 | 2013-05-28 |        
| 2a.jpg     | 2013-05-22 | 2013-05-28 |   
| 2b.jpg     | 2013-05-22 | 2013-05-28 |  
| 2c.jpg     | 2013-05-22 | 2013-05-28 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

There are much more data are present in similar format like 3.jpg, 3a.jpg, 3b.jpg, 41.jpg etc.

I am using this query to query the database :-

**SELECT `adv_images` WHERE `adv_images` REGEXP BINARY '^(2+[a-z]?)';**

My requirement here is to pull only those adv_images which starts with 2 only(i.e 2.jpg, 2a.jpg etc). But its pulling 21.jpg, 22.jpg, 22a.jpg etc.

How can we fix it.

Comment: [RegexPAL](http://regexpal.com/) for testing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
^([2+][a-z]?)\.jpg
```

So your query becomes

```
SELECT adv_images WHERE adv_images REGEXP BINARY '^([2+][a-z]?)\.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Benjamin, this would be the perfect match in your case:

`^2([a-zA-Z]?)+\.jpg`

Meaning:

- Start with `2`
- Followed by zero or one alpha
- Followed by `.jpg`

Comment: @Benjamin: I've clarified my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
SELECT adv_images WHERE adv_images + 0 = 2;
```

Comment: if you also like to chack ".jpg" extension also then you can add it to condition as ` AND adv_images like '%.jpg'`.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean you cannot cast "2.jpg" to a number by adding `+ 0`.

Comment: When you do addition in mysql to string mysql converts that string to number by itself so if you do `"123abcd" + 0` mysql returns 123

Comment: Hey Dharmesh, its working for me, but can we do it using regx. that would be helpfl for me

Comment: You can try this: `SELECT adv_images FROM table WHERE adv_images REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]][a-z]';`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for trying this, But I have found a simple way to the solution.

**SELECT adv_images WHERE adv_images REGEXP BINARY '^(2+[a-z]?)'**; I was trying this, but now I have just added a '.' in the regx

ex-

**SELECT adv_images WHERE adv_images REGEXP BINARY '^(2+[a-z.]?)'**; and its working perfect for me.

Comment: The reason for this is `2.jpg` was not followed by an alpha. On the second query it works because `2.jpg` is followed by either an alpha or a dot.

Comment: You should however leave out the questionmark, this will still match `23.jpg` because your condition `[a-z.]` is optional due to `?`.